# norm with respect to matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In Short:

I am studying robotics. I have an equation that asks me to take the norm of a vector with respect to a matrix. I do not know what that means.

In long: When I read norm, and I am working with vectors, I think of the Euclidean Norm or the magnitude: $||\textbf{x}|| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + ... x_n^2}$.

I am uncertain on how the matrix that I am taking that value with respect to changes it.

The exact equation I am considering here is: 
$$f(q_{t+1}) = ||q_{t+1} - q_t||^2_w + ||y^*_{t+1} -\phi({q_t})||^2_C$$
Which, when minimized gives the optimal joint command $q_{t+1}$ for a robotic arm moving to the coordinates $y^*$. $W$ and $C$ are both matrices of the size $|q| \times |q|$.

I give the robotic information for context only. I have a very good understanding of that, I am just deeply confused by the "with respect to" phrase. What does it mean? How do these matrices change the norm? Does it regulate it in some way? Is it like normalizing a random variable (dividing an r.v. by its highest possible value). Any light would help.

Comment: we don't know either. Your book should have some preliminary material earlier that settles things. If not, you need a more basic book. That being said, given two "things" in linear spaces where one depends on the other, say $g(M) = X,$ you can always find a directional derivative in the direction, say $N,$ given by $\frac{d}{dt} f(M + t N)$ at $t=0.$ Here $M,N$ could be matrices, $X$ a vector. Might be relevant, might not.

Comment: I looked and looked through out, but no luck. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Could it possibly be $||q||_A^2=q^T A q$? Notice that $||q||^2=q^T q$. Two vectors $p, q$ are orthogonal if $q^T p=0$. They are said to be $A$-orthogonal if $q^T A p=0$ for some positive definite matrix $A$. This might be related.

Comment: KittyL, you have nailed it. I was going over slides from another school, and they gave that exact formula (I was just coming over here to paste my discovery). Well done! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As KittyL figured out intuitively, and as listed in the University of Edinburgh's Robotics: Science and Systems slides.

$$||v||^2_W = v^TWv$$

reference:
http://wcms.inf.ed.ac.uk/ipab/rss/lecture-notes-2015-2016/3.RSS-Kinematics.pdf

[Image of the slide from the course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMkxT.jpg)

Comment: The reference redirects to a login page. Can you find an alternate link?

Comment: I added an image I took of the slide to my answer. I do not feel comfortable adding my professor's entire slide set, though I wish I could.